# When will I be able to ask about systemd questions with ubuntu?

Tags: support, asking-questions, scope

This one was deleted:

[Increase Trackpoint Sensititvity with SystemD (Ubuntu 15.04 or later)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596085/increase-trackpoint-sensititvity-with-systemd)

because SystemD is a feature in the next version of Ubuntu. Having reinstalled, I searched for the solution to this systemd issue, and it happened to be the number 1 result on google.

I want to ask the question again; When can I? Or would it be possible to reopen this question?

Comment: On [April 23rd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseSchedule)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got a response why the question was deleted: Because 15.04 Vivid Vervet is [still a development release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseSchedule) and if it would have been me, the comment would have been: "We're sorry but [bug reports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu (like 15.04) should be [reported on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs) so that developers can see, track and fix these issues."

Which should fully answer your question for the present and the future...  **;-)**

Comment: How can this be classified as a bug? This is asking, "How do you accomplish x in systemd"?

Comment: @Akiva "systemd destroyed x". I can see how that would be seen as a bug. But I guess what you really meant was "my upstart job doesn't work anymore. How can I get equivalent behaviour with systemd?" which is more of a question. I don't think your question is off-topic because [systemd can be installed on supported versions of Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/420917/how-can-i-replace-upstart-with-systemd) and 15.04 will be released in days. I've undeleted your question. Please edit it to include the upstart job as well be more precise about what you really mean. Thanks!